# Can I publish something which is more like a study and which does not contain any concrete results?

Tags: publications, physics, publishability

I am a theoretical physics researcher. I have not published any papers yet, so I do not have that much experience in publishing a paper. Though I am a Ph.D. student, I am also working independently on another topic of interest (physics only) and trying to find out something. This topic is different from my Ph.D. topic, and I am doing this research on my own without anyone's help.  I have collected information from google (mostly some websites and from a few research papers), and based on this information, I am trying to do my research. My doubt is - if I didn't get any concrete results, can I still publish my work just as a study? Like publishing some article with the title - "Study of ----"? What if it is just collecting data from different sources and gathering it in one place, what if I didn't find anything new from my data analysis? Can I still publish it?

Comment: Are you trying to make a survey paper since you don't have results? These are fairly common in mathematical physics.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Are you saying review paper? No, I am not doing a review paper.

Comment: For the wrong reason, there is something called vanity press, where you publish a book on your own. The name is quite derogatory, but this way of publishing is not a bad thing by itself.
Your research without results fits in publishing a book on the topic, a kind of PhD thesis without results.

Answer (score 5):

This seems unlikely if you mean publish with a reputable publisher. The difficulty will be finding someone, other than yourself who will publish it.

You can, of course, publish it yourself on arXiv or similar, though you may need some help from a professor to get an account there. Your university email address may be enough.

But formal publishers are looking for novel *results* and advances to the state of the art, which you don't seem to have at the moment.

Talk to a professor or to so that you understand the possible consequences of publishing early. On the one hand, your ideas get out there attached to your name. But on the other hand, others are also free to extend your work, even before you do.